# NLog: how to specify log folder at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, nlog

For an example, i have following code (ASP.NET core 6):

Program.cs:

```
//...
var config = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();
var logfile = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("logfile") 
    {
        FileName = Path.Combine(AppFolderPath, "log", "${var:myLogName}", "log_${date:format=dd-MM-yyyy}.txt") 
    };
config.AddRule(NLog.LogLevel.Trace, NLog.LogLevel.Fatal, logfile);
LogManager.Configuration = config;
//...
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    services.AddSingleton<ISomeClass, SomeClass>(_ => new SomeClass(LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()));
}
```

SomeClass.cs:

```
public class SomeClass(ILogger logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

private ILogger _logger;
```

... then somewhere in class:

```
foreach(var a in b)
{
    var thread = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var myLogName = a.Name;
        _logger.Trace("Hello!");
    }
}
```

My goal is to create all subfolders for each started thread with myLogName as result:

```
AppFolderPath\log\myLogName1\log_25-04-2022.txt
AppFolderPath\log\myLogName2\log_25-04-2022.txt
AppFolderPath\log\myLogName3\log_25-04-2022.txt
```

But i can see only one file

```
AppFolderPath\log\log_25-04-2022.txt
```

So myLogName variable is just skipped and this file contains one log string "Hello!" per started thread. How can i configure NLog to make folders as i want? Only by using GDC and making extension-methods with updating global resource each time i want write a log?

UPD1: solution with GDC works, but its not so thread-safe, i can see that some log files contains many strings (expected only 1) and some threads were'nt created any log files:

```
public static class LoggerExtensions
{
    public static NLog.ILogger WithMyLog(this NLog.ILogger logger, string myLogName)
    {
        GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("myLogName", myLogName);
        return logger;
    }
}
```

... and then:

```
foreach(var a in b)
{
    var thread = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var myLogName = a.Name;
        _logger.WithMyLog(myLogName).Trace("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Very expected tho, no questions to this mechanism. Maybe i should add some more extension methods and fill them with lock statements to make this work properly.

Comment: I'd really like to talk you out of this. For one: it's going to be dirrrty stuff going on. And it's going to perform poorly. If you want to filter your Logs for some property, pass it along with the context into structured logging and log to a Database or Log-Analysis Service. Then you can easily filter for whatever you like _and_ it will probably perform much better than File-I/O into N Files.

Comment: @Fildor I absolutely agree that logging into special services or databases is much more efficient and logs can be viewed easily and sometimes even very beautifully, but, unfortunately, this is not an option, since the end user will be the one who does not have access to services and having no need to develop separate solutions for viewing logs. Therefore, there is a need to log specifically to text files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very simple: just use structured logging! According to [this NLog article](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer), NLog 4.5+ can use properties directly from arguments:

```
var logfile = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("logfile") 
    {
        FileName = Path.Combine(AppFolderPath, "log", "${event-properties:item=myLogName}", "log_${date:format=dd-MM-yyyy}.txt") 
    };
config.AddRule(NLog.LogLevel.Trace, NLog.LogLevel.Fatal, logfile);
```

and then:

```
_logger.Trace("{myLogName}", a.Name);
```

Comment: It might become a security issue that Logging-Event-Parameter suddenly can control the file-path. Maybe it can be used to modify system files.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe consider using [${logger}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logger-Layout-Renderer()) or [${threadName}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ThreadName-Layout-Renderer)

Example:

```
var logfile = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("logfile") 
    {
        FileName = Path.Combine(AppFolderPath, "log", "${logger}", "log_${date:format=dd-MM-yyyy}.txt") 
    };
```

By specifying a custom token in the Logger-Name-Filter, then you can ensure only special "thread-loggers" will reach the "logfile". Ex:

```
config.AddRule(NLog.LogLevel.Trace, NLog.LogLevel.Fatal, logfile, "*CustomToken*");
```

Then just ensure the Logger-Name contains the token:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    services.AddSingleton<ISomeClass, SomeClass>(_ => new SomeClass(LogManager.GetLogger("SomeClassCustomToken")));
}
```

If you place the custom-token as prefix (Ex. `"CustomToken.SomeClass"`), then you can strip it away using `${logger:shortName=true}` in `FileName="..."`